# JavaScript rounding to two digits does not always work

Tags: javascript, rounding

I have a incremental control in the UI that increase/decrease values by clicking left and right arrows.
See the UI Image:

[image]

I'm trying to round a float returned by UI to two decimal points. It works most of the times but I get raw values once in a while.
Here is the sample code"

```js
input = document.getElementById("in");
input.addEventListener("input", function() {
    console.log(input.value + " rounded : " + Math.round((input.value  - 0.01) * 100) / 100);
});
```

```html
<input id="in" type="number"></input>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the magical values that do not work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: You should at very least include values in your question taht are throwing an error or that are not giving you the expected outcome you desire.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to round to at most 2 decimal places, if necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/how-to-round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-if-necessary). You want the second answer, not the accepted one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11832950/6943587

Answer (score 0):

that's just how it goes with floats and computers, sometimes it just slightly misses.

use .toFixed(2) to round to 2 decimal places.